# Sum of a sequence by using for and while loop

Tags: java, sequence, counting

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Last Number ");
        int inputedNumber = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextInt());
        int result = 0;
        int outcome = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < inputedNumber; i++) {
            result += ;
        }
        /*/*while (outcome <= inputedNumber) {
            result += inputedNumber;
            outcome++;
        }*/
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I have a problem to understand what is wrong here, because I would like to solve the task , originally it should be (Implement a program, which calculates the sum 1+2+3+...+n where n is given as user input.) but it gives me another answer, please , pin out for me in a both way , to understand what I went wrong , because everything so far make sense for me , but code doesn't work as it should to be

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= inputedNumber; i++) {
    result += i;
}
```

**Note:** you should start with `i=1` based on your requirement:

> 1+2+3+..+n

Comment: sure thing, kindly upvote and accept answer if all issues were solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace result += ; with result += i;

Answer (score 0):

For the first case. This is not a valid Java code, you should put a value/variable after += operator.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputedNumber; i++) {
  result += ;
}
```

If you put the variable i after it, and use i<= inputedNumber. You will get the expected answer.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= inputedNumber; i++) {
  result += i;
}
```

In the second case, you are actually doing n*(n+1)

```
while (outcome <= inputedNumber) {
   result += inputedNumber;
   outcome++;
}
```

This can be tested as input the value as 2:

The first iteration:

```
outcome -> 0
inputedNumber -> 2
result -> 2

The second iteration:
outcome -> 1
inputedNumber -> 2
result -> 4


The third iteration:
outcome -> 2
inputedNumber -> 2
result -> 6
```

The fix is similar to what I suggested before. You could take this as an exercise.